# get form input value from form_class in views

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-forms, django-views

How do I access the company_id field in form input in the class based views

forms.py

```
    class CompanyProductForm(forms.Form):
        company_id = forms.IntegerField()
```

I tried overriding the form_valid() but didn't work out.
also I want to convert 'obj' queryset to a python list and then append it to products.

view.py

```
    class CompanyProduct(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, FormView):
        template_name = 'company_product.html'
        form_class = CompanyProductForm
        products = []

        def test_func(self):
            return self.request.user.is_staff

        def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            self.products = []

            def form_valid(self, form):
                id = form.cleaned_data['company_id']
                return super(CompanyProduct, self).form_valid(form)

            obj = Product.objects.filter(company_id=id)



            return render(request, 'product_download.html',{'product':self.products,
                                                    'num':len(self.products)})
```

Error:

TypeError at /upload/company_product/

int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'builtin_function_or_method'

Comment: Your form could be invalid, hence control won't be reaching to form_valid

Comment: Your line in `form_valid()` should be `id = form.cleaned_data['company_id']` with underscore. Try overriding `form_invalid()` and check whether form actually passes validation.

Comment: @FazilZaid It was a typo error here only. In my code it's 'company_id'. My question is now that how do i give reference to this id in ocject filter.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with what you have tried. You said it didn't workout. Is there any error message?? or did you check if your form actually passess the validation? Also, in the `form_valid()` function the last line should be calling the `super()` function, not rendering the template. So, change it to `return super(CompanyProduct, self).form_valid(form)`

Comment: @FazilZaid I'm extremely sorry, i used wrong indentation while posting question,now I have edited the question just the way I wrote. Please have a look now

Answer (score 1):

By overriding the `post` method with just an assignment you have disabled all the other actions that are supposed to happen on post, such as validating the form. You should remove that method altogether - define that list somewhere else, such as in `form_valid`.

Comment: That and it's a class property. Pick one and stick with it.

Comment: sorry for trouble but that was my typo problem in indentation while posting the question. please have a look to the edited question

Comment: That makes it worse. Your version of form_valid is now never called, cause there is no `CompanyProduct.form_valid`. There is only a `CompanyProduct.post.form_valid`. As Daniel says, there's no need to override the post method. I can only think of one or two cases, where I needed to do that.

Comment: @Melvyn can you please tell me what to do exactly to get form input and append the queryset to the list

Comment: **Remove your `post` method** and restore `form_valid` to normal indentation.

Comment: @DanielRoseman then how will I render the template with context dictionary